# $X_{25}$ Point in a Triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangle-centres

I saw the main problem, which I have described as Theorem 5 below, on C. Kimberling's website. I made some attempts to prove the problem with geometric methods. I wrote notes. I will present them below. I don't know only the proof of **Theorem 5 (Main Problem)**.

This question **doesn't** includes multiple questions in one. It focus on Theorem 5 only. So the **main problem** is **Theorem 5**. I have given other theorems with their proofs. Because they contain my efforts that can be useful in solving the main problem.

[image]

***My Efforts:***

**Theorem 1.** Let $ABC$ be any triangle. $O$ is the circumcenter, $DEF$ is the orthic triangle, $KLM$ is the tangential triangle of the triangle $ABC$. (In other words, the triangle $ABC$ is the contact triangle of the triangle $KLM$.) Then $DE \parallel KL$, $DF \parallel KM$, $EF \parallel LM$.

**Theorem 2.** $OA \perp EF$, $OB \perp DF$, $OC \perp DE$.

**Theorem 3.** The lines $KD$, $LE$, $MF$ are concurrent at the point denoted by $X_{25}$.

**Theorem 4.** If the midpoints of the triangle $ABC$ are $P$, $R$, $S$ then the lines $KP$, $LR$, $MS$ intersect at the point $O$.

**Proof of Th 1.** Let $\angle BAC =\alpha $. By properties of the orthic triangle $ \angle EDC = \angle FDB = \alpha $. $\angle BOC = 2 \angle BAC = 2\alpha$. $OB \perp KM$ and $OC \perp KL$, so $ \angle BKC = 180^\circ -2\alpha$. Since $|KB|=|KC|$, we get $ \angle KBC = \angle KCB = \alpha $. By the equality of alternate interior angles, we conclude that $DF \parallel KM$, $DE \parallel KL$. Similarly, we understand that $EF \parallel LM$.

**Proof of Th 2.** The circumcircle of $ABC$ is the incircle of $KLM$. Hence $OA \perp LM$. By Theorem 1, $EF \parallel LM$. Similarly, we get $OB \perp DF$, $OC \perp DE$.

**Proof of Th 3.** By theorem 1, $DF \parallel KM$, $DE \parallel KL$, $EF \parallel LM$. So $DEF \sim KLM$ are similar triangles and they are homothetic. Therefore, the lines $KD$, $LE$, $MF$ are concur at a point (in the homothetic center $X_{25}$).

**Proof of Th 4.** Since $BOCK$ is a kite, we find $OK \perp BC$ and $OK$ bisect $[BC]$. So $OK$ passes through $P$ that the midpoint of $[BC]$. Similarly, $OL$ passes through $R$ and $OM$ passes through $S$. That is, all the lines $KP$, $LR$, $MS$ pass through the point $O$.

$\color{red}{\textbf{Main Problem (Theorem 5.)}}$ The point $X_{25}$ is on the Euler line of triangle $ABC$.

I will be glad if you share your ideas and solutions for the proof of Theorem 5.

**Other Useful Notes and My Comments:**

**1.** Orthic Triangle is [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthicTriangle.html) and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)#Orthic_triangle)

**2.** Tangential Triangle is [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentialTriangle.html) and Contact Triangle is [there](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContactTriangle.html#:%7E:text=The%20contact%20triangle%20is%20the%20polar%20triangle%20of%20the%20incircle.&text=the%20reference%20triangle-,.,area%20as%20the%20extouch%20triangle.&text=approaches%20an%20equilateral%20triangle%20(Goldoni%202003).)

**3.** Euler Line is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line)

**4.** Theorems that are equivalent to the statements of Theorems 1-2-4 or that will enable us to obtain these theorems as a result are given in Advanced Euclidean Geometry by Roger Johnson (1929), page 172.

**5.** R. Johnson did not specify the concurrency in Theorem 3. I understand that he saw the homothetic between $DEF$ and $KLM$. Therefore, I don't think that he coluld't see concurrency of the lines at the homotethic center.  (My opininon: R. Johnson knew but didn't write it, probably because it was easy.)

**6.** Theorem 5 does not exist in R. Johnson either. C. Kimbeling's [website](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) is given as a feature without proof.

Comment: $X_{25}$ seems to be the orthocenter of triangles $\triangle{DEF}$ and $\triangle{KLM}$.

Comment: @Piquito Thanks for your interest. I checked it with using Geometer's Sketchpad. Unfortunately, $X_{25}$ is not the orthocenter of $\triangle DEF$ and $\triangle KLM$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_1,B_1,C_1$ be the mid points of the segments $HA$, $HB$, $HC$, so that the Euler circle $\odot(9)$ of $\Delta ABC$ passes through the nine points $D,E,F;P,Q,R;A_1,B_1,C_1$. Let $9$ be the center of $\odot(9)$.

[image: A geometric property of the triangle center X(25)]

The lines $AB$ and $DE$ are "antiparallel" w.r.t. the lines $CEA$ and $CDB$, so $ABCE$ is cyclic, so the point $H$ has the same power $\Pi_1$ w.r.t. the circle $\odot(ABCE)$ when computed as $HA\cdot HD$, respectively as $HB\cdot HE$. After a cyclic permutation of $A,B,C$ we see that $HC\cdot HF$ is equal to the same power $\Pi_1$.

It is known that $AH=2AA_1=2A_1H=2OP$. To see this, one can argument as follows.
The triangle $\Delta A_1DP$ has the vertices on $(9)$, and a right angle in $D$, so $A_1P$ is a diameter of $\odot(9)$, $9$ is the mid point,
so it is on the perpendicular bisector for the segment $DP$, and with the same argument also for $QE$ and $RF$.
The mid point of $OH$ is the only point with this property, so it is $9$.
Then the diagonals of $OA_1HP$ intersect in their mid points, so it is a parallelogram, so $A_1H=OP$. The similar relations $B_1H=OQ$, $C_1H=OR$ are then valid with the same argument.

The direction $QP\|AB$ is again antiparallel to the direction $KL\|DE$, so $QPKL$ is cyclic, so the point $O$ has the same power $\Pi_2$ w.r.t. the circle $\odot(QPKL)$ when computed as $OP\cdot OK$, respectively as $OQ\cdot OL$. After a cyclic permutation of $A,B,C$ we see that $OR\cdot OM$ is equal to the same power $\Pi_2$. Putting all together (and ignoring signs):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Pi_1 &=HA\cdot HD=HB\cdot HE=HC\cdot HF\ ,\\
2\Pi_2 &=2OP\cdot OK=2OQ\cdot OL=2OR\cdot OM\ ,\\[3mm]
\frac{\Pi_1}{2\Pi_2}
&
=\frac{HA\cdot HD}{2OP\cdot OK}
=\frac{HB\cdot HE}{2OQ\cdot OL}
=\frac{HC\cdot HF}{2OR\cdot OM}
\\
&
=\color{blue}{
 \frac{HD}{OK}
=\frac{HE}{OL}
=\frac{HF}{OM}}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $Y$ be the point on the Euler line $OH$ of $\Delta ABC$ with the property that
$$
\color{blue}{
\frac {YH}{YO}
}
$$
has the same common value of the previous three fractions.
Then we have the similarities of triangles
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta YHD&\sim\Delta YOK\ ,\\
\Delta YHE&\sim\Delta YOL\ ,\\
\Delta YHF&\sim\Delta YOM\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so $Y$ is also on the lines $DK$, $EL$, $FM$, i.e. $Y=X_{25}$.
(It is the center of homothey that maps $\Delta DEF$ to $\Delta KLM$.)

$\square$

Comment: This is an elegant solution! (But there is a little typo, $ABCE$ is not cyclic. Correction: $ABDE$ is cyclic.)